# Is there a mono repo library which allows us to use typescript packages with type suggestions without compiling?

Tags: typescript, lerna, pnpm

Let's say I have a mono repo like this:

```
repo
 |--- package1
 |--- package2
```

Both packages are written in TypeScript. I need to use `package1` inside `package2`. Currently I'm using lerna (Planning to switch to pnpm) and if I want to use `package1` inside any other package, I first have to build it and generate the `index.d.ts` type definition file in order to get type completion wherever I use it. It would be really great If I can do this without compilation so that during the development, I can easily keep working without re building `package1` every time I update it. At the moment, I have a watcher set for this which takes a lot of resources from my machine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want to considering typescript references
https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/project-references.html